# download CSV file from a URL based on inputs from a ticker_list?

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and I want to make a program that does the following:

1. Use this `list = [aapl,goog,jnj,msft]` as input
2. Go to the url `"https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=goog&output=csv"` and replace `"goog"` with tickers from list above
3. Finally save the CSV file onto the file system.

The image contains the code i have been able to think of

```
from urllib import request
ticker_list = "aapl"
response = request.urlretrieve("https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q="+ticker_list+"&output=csv",'D:/LatestStockFile.csv')
#[aapl,goog,xom,ge,msft,bp,c,pg,wmt,pfe,tm,jnj] 
# I want tickers from this list to append instead of ticker_list

# also if possible a different file name to save for each iteration of ticker
# example : say ticker = "aaple" then this "aapl" should be appended to url and path: "D:/Apple.csv"

def download_csv(ticker,path):
    response = request.urlretrieve(ticker,path)

def user_input():
 choice = input("enter choice: 1/2/3\n")
 if choice == 1:
  download_csv("aapl","D:/Apple.csv")
 elif choice == 2:
  download_csv=("goog","D:/Google.csv")
 elif choice == 3:
  download_csv("jnj","D:/Johnson.csv")

user_input()
```

Comment: Share what you have done so far so that others can help you.

Comment: Here is my Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list = ["aapl", "goog", "jnj", "msft"]
    for items in list:
        req = requests.get('https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=' + items + '&output=csv')
        with open(items+".csv","w") as file:
            file.write(req.text)
```

Comment: @GarefieldCat i tried your code but it says "Response object has no attribute Contents"

Comment: @GarefieldCat Thanks your code works as desired but i can't seem to understand exactly how it works especially the __name__ = "__main__" ,

Comment: @GarefieldCat also where does the path comes from

Comment: The code look through the list, next in for-loop cycle set each value to url. using requests library it downloads it and write to file. File are stored in script main directory. if __name__ == '__main__': # this is the main program string, you could delete it for now

Comment: @GarefieldCat "The code look throu" ? pls explain the working of the code

Comment: @GarefieldCat  can you suggest an answer based on the code that i wrote i wan't to know what i did wrong?

Comment: @NitinSingh what you did wrong in your own code  was simply not doing anything with the response you get. You need to extract the csv data part from the response and save it somewhere.

Comment: @Gnudiff so what should have i done can you edit my original code for the same

Comment: uhm... that's what this answer is about

Answer (score 0):

The answer by GarfieldCat is good for its use case, but doesn't directly address your request of having the stock name as the CSV file name.  It's just the ticker name.

What you can do is define a dictionary key-value data structure to hold the company name as well as the stock name. For example, adapt your existing list to something like:

```
stocks =  [
    {
        'ticker': 'aapl',
        'company: 'Apple'
    },
    {
        'ticker: 'goog',
        'company: 'Google'
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

Then use the code from GarfieldCat, just adapted to extract data from the dict:

```
for item in stocks:
    url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q={}&output=csv'.format(item.get('ticker')) 
    req = requests.get(url)
    with open('{}.csv'.format(item.get('company')), 'wb') as f:
       f.write(req.text)
```

If you continue to have questions about this, I would suggest you look in to the `request` library documentation for how to get data from a request, and then read about Python writing to files.

Comment: We write csv file which are text so we do not need "wb" just "w" in with open('{}.csv'.format(item.get('company'), 'w') as f:

Comment: @Jason with open('{}.csv'.format(item.get('company'), 'wb') as f:
       f.write(req.text) this line is causing error "invalid syntax"

Comment: missing parens for the `item.get` method.  should be three closing parens total, and original was two.  fixed.

Comment: @GarfieldCat true.  I work primarily in 2.7 due to lib restrictions, so that's my preferred way of opening files.  3.x changed that

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way?

```
"""
"""
#in this file "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/amex.txt"
#you have the following tickers
#ibm
#sbux
#msft
"""

import urllib
import re
import json

symbolslist = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/amex.txt").read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

for symbol in symbolslist:
    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "w+")
    myfile.close()

    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/"+ symbol+ ":US")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    datapoints = data["data_values"]

    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "a")
    for point in datapoints:
        myfile.write(str(symbol+","+str(point[0])+","+str(point[1])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

Here is an option that is similar, but different (you are reading from a tuple not a text file).

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

Output_File = open('C:/Users/rshuell001/Historical_Prices.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```